# Transfer specific cells from each filtered area

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code which transfers all visible data from "Prepsheet" to "Contract".

The code refers to each visible section in Prepsheet, resizes the area in contract and then transfers the data.

I want to refer to specific columns within the filtered area, so that I can transfer column specific data individually. For example, I may only want to transfer the 1st and 6th columns. Please can someone assist

```
Public rnga As Range
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    Dim sourceWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Set sourceWS = Prepsheet

    Dim filteredDataRange As Excel.Range

    Set filteredDataRange = sourceWS.AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1, 0)

     Set filteredDataRange = filteredDataRange.Resize(filteredDataRange.Rows.CountLarge - 1)

    Set filteredDataRange = filteredDataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

      Dim destinationWS As Excel.Worksheet

      Dim destinationRow As Long
      destinationRow = 1

         Dim area As Excel.Range
         For Each area In filteredDataRange.Areas
            Set rnga = area
            MatchSelectionArea
        Next area
End Sub

Sub MatchSelectionArea()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Dim nRows As Long
Dim nCols As Long
Set cel = Contract.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)


    nRows = rnga.Rows.Count
    nCols = rnga.Columns.Count



    Set rng = cel.Resize(nRows, nCols)
    rng.Value = rnga.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: `Prepsheet` is undefined.

Comment: Hi, Prepsheet is the sheet's code name

Answer (score 0):

You are delving too deeply into the filtered rows and using the number of filtered rows to redefine the filtered range. You can copy straight out of a filtered range and you will only paste the visible rows.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook, fdRng As Range, v As Long, vCOLs As Variant
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet, destinationWS As Worksheet

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = wb.Worksheets("Prepsheet")
    vCOLs = Array(1, 3, 5) 'columns A, C and E

    With sourceWS
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            With .AutoFilter.Range
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    For v = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
                        .Columns(vCOLs(v)).Copy _
                          destination:='YOU HAVE PROVIDED NO DEFINED DESTINATION
                    Next v
                End With
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub MatchSelectionArea()
    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim nRows As Long, nCols As Long

    With Worksheets("Contract")
        Set cel = .Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

        nRows = rnga.Rows.Count
        nCols = rnga.Columns.Count

        'cannot determine what this actually does
        Set rng = cel.Resize(nRows, nCols)
        rng = rnga.Value
    End With

End Sub
```